# Querying root and indirect sibling views in Android ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` to show a list of articles. Each `ListView` element is a `LinearLayout`. On each article, there is a `TextView` button to edit the title (another `TextView`). However, the button and the title are not under a direct parent (and actually not at the same level).

A sample structure is shown below:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_zone">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_popularity">
    </LinearLayout><!--end of title_zone-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_zone">
        ...
    </LinearLayout><!--end of content_zone-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_zone">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/author_buttons">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_title_button"
                android:onClick="editTitle">
            ...
        </LinearLayout><!--end of author_buttons-->
    </LinearLayout><!--end of button_zone-->
</LinearLayout>
```

I write a `SimpleAdapter` to apply data to views, so the root `LinearLayout` will have a tag of the article ID. When `editTitle()` is called, it needs to find its *parent's parent's parent* to the root. And after new title is entered, a message will send to server containing new title and the article ID. Also, the title text will be changed visually, which means I need to find the title `TextView` based on the root.

The problem is that this querying root process is tightly coupled to the UI structure. If I changed the structure in XML, I need to pay attention to change the querying code in Java. (The querying title view is relatively easy, if the root is obtained.)

Is there a more maintainable way to implement my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. A solution that works for my situation is as follows:

In the customized simple adapter for this `ListView`, set the article ID as the `edit_title_button`'s tag. And set the article ID composed string as the *root LinearLayout*'s tag, e.g., "*a_123*" if the article ID is *123*.

So, when `editTitle(View v)` is called, we can get the story ID by `v.getTag()`. Of course, we can also get the `ListView` by its ID (e.g., `ListView list=findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);`). Then, we can simply get the *root LinearLayout* by `list.findViewWithTag("a_123")`.

Since the *root LinearLayout* is obtained without knowing the UI structure, following codes are easy to maintain.